# Trying to invoke dimmer/throbber Before/During Ajax

Tags: php, ajax, jquery, throbber

Here is what I want to / am trying to do.

There is a form.  The form has a submit button.  the onMouseDown() event for the submit button is:

```
<input type='submit' value='Search' name='save' id='save' onmousedown = 'DimOn("test.php", "SearchResultDiv")' />
```

Now, once the button is clicked I want it to do three things in EXACT order.

1) Dim the page.

2) Perform the Ajax Query, and Populate the search Results.

3) Remove the Dim.

**EDIT:**

Even tried using the beforeSend, and Complete events in jQuery object

```
function DimOn(sUrl, sElement) 
{
    jQueryAjax(sUrl, sElement);
}

function jQueryAjax(sUrl, sElement) 
{
    $.ajax({
        url: sUrl,
        type: 'GET',
        async: false,
        cache: false,
        timeout: 1000,
        beforeSend: function(){
            $('#dim').fadeIn();
        },  
        complete : function(){
            $('#dim').fadeOut();
        },      
        error: function(){
            return true;
        },
        success: function(msg){ 
            if (msg != '')
                PopulateResponse(msg, sElement, false);
            else 
                PopulateResponse("An Error Has Occured.", sElement, false);
        }
    });
}
```

Currently, it will appear to do it like this:

2) Perform the Ajax Query, and Populate the search Results.

2) Dim the page.

3) Remove the Dim.

Where the result populate (takes ten seconds) and the dimmer flashes on and off very quickly.

Please lend me a hand fellow programmers, I am no stranger to this technology, and why I turned async off, to try to get stuff to happen in order, but still NO DICE.

Comment: You can highlight your code with your mouse and then click the "code" button (looks like `{}`) which will add the very typical four spaces garbage markup for you.

Comment: That worked great...  I would always click the button labeled "Code"... I guess I expected that to work for "Code"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved this issue with this function:

```
function jax(sUrl, sElement, bEval, sType, bAsync) 
{
    $.ajax({
        url: sUrl,
        type: sType,
        async: true,
        cache: false,
        timeout: 30000,
        error: function()
        {
            return true;
        },
        beforeSend: function(){
            $('div#dim').fadeIn(400);
        },  
        complete : function(){
            $('div#dim').fadeOut(200);
            if(sUrl.search(/scroll=true/ig) != -1)
                goToByScroll(sElement);

        },                      
        success: function(msg){ 
            if (msg != '')
            {
                PopulateResponse(msg, sElement, bEval);
            }
            else
            {
                PopulateResponse("An error has occurred.", sElement, bEval)
                //Coming soon, ajax call to php file to log javascript failure.
            }
        }
    });
}
```

This CSS

```
div#dim
{
    background-color:#000;
    -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=60)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=60);
    opacity:.6;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    z-index:1005;
    display:none;
    cursor:wait;
}

div#dim div
{

    position:relative;
    top:400px;
    z-index:1006;
    text-align:center;
    cursor:wait;
}

div#dim div img
{
    z-index:1007;
    text-align:center;
    border:none;
    cursor:wait;
}
```

and This HTML

```
<div id='dim'><div style="text-align:center;"><img src="Images/Loading/loading10.gif" alt="Loading... please wait" title="Loading... please wait" /></div></div>
```